# Openshift resource limit and pagecache

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm running a Kafka cluster on Openshift. As I understand, the Kafka performance relies on pagecache. I was trying to understand how best I can limit the resource on Kafka container so it works efficiently.

Linux tries to use the available RAM for buffer to speed up the disk operations. Assuming there is only Kafka container running on a node, if I set the limit on the container to 5Gi, then the rest of available memory on the node would be used for buffer/cache I believe.

I was wondering if I set the limit to 10Gi and if the Kafka use only 5GB, would the remaining unused 5GB be still available for pagecahce to the Operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't reserve memory, it just puts a cap on how much the application can use. So I don't believe it should affect how the operating system handles kernel buffer/cache.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if the container requests for 10Gi and limits to 10Gi that means it is guaranteed to have 10GB. In this case does the Openshift reserves the memory for the container?

Comment: If the application inside the container doesn't use whole 10GB, would the remaining be available for pagecache?

If there is another application on the same node running in besteffort mode, would Openshift somehow limit it's usage to guarantee that 10GB is available to the other application?

Comment: The request amount is used by the scheduler to determine which node is best to place a node. An application will not be placed on a node if its request cannot be satisfied. If it has a limit set as well, as its memory use grows, the scheduler can bump a best effort application to another node to allow the one with a limit to use it. This all happens within the realm of the Kubernetes scheduler and are decisions made independent of underlying way operating system handles memory.

Comment: The kernels use of memory for buffers and cache is exactly the same as it would be for a normal system. If processes (even though running in a container), use up actual memory, then that obviously can reduce what the kernel can use for buffers and cache. Kubernetes and OpenShift doesn't change that.